# Possible arrangements of chain on 2d grid

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have a chain with $N$ links on an x-y grid (can only be oriented along x or y). I know the distances from the start point to the end point to be $L_x$ and $L_y$. How can I find all the possible arrangements of this chain? and is it possible to know how many segments are typically oriented in the y direction? I feel like this problem is somewhat similar to a random walk, however I am not familiar with 2d random walks, and I'm not sure where to start here

edit: The chain can go up, down, left, right, but it cant overlap or cross

Comment: What restrictions do we have here? If we can only go up and right, this is just Manhattan Walks. Can we go left and down? Can we overlap previous links?

Comment: It can up, down, left, right, but it cant overlap or cross

Comment: Let $N=|L_x|+|L_y|+k$: if $k=0$ then this is easy; for particular small values of $k$ you can make some progress; but otherwise there's not going to be a closed-form solution, because the no-overlapping constraint is intractable.